# Deltajen, Opendelta, and xdelta

Tags: updates, custom-roms, ota-update

Does anyone have experience with any delta system? I would like to create delta's of my ROMS I have tried Deltajen and found it does not properly.
I have ROM(A).zip and ROM(B).zip containing system.img and NON-HLOS.bin boot.img etc etc. When I run Deltajen  it gives me a zip file with a blank updater-script.